# How can I add Apple MusicKit to a React Native app?

Tags: react-native, expo, apple-musickit

How can I implement Apple MusicKit in a React Native app, including Apple authentication?

Comment: Find anything out yet? Would be happy for a non-expo solution too

Comment: Maybe https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/apple-musickit-and-api?

Comment: Did you find anything out yet ? Is the native modules feature of react native suitable for this issue ? https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-intro

Can we create MusicKit SDK of IOS and android as native modules on react native?

I don't have too much experience with react native but it seems suitable for this issue.